# Compile-time generation of a subset of class methods

Tags: c++, stl

I am developing a programming interface for several devices by various manufacturers. Most manufacturers typically produce at least a dozen models. Commands and data are sent to the devices as low-level instructions. The problem is that although no two devices support the same set of instructions and there is considerable overlap between the set of instructions that most devices support.

Because the low-level instructions are quirky I plan to wrap them in intuitively-named class methods, so that I don't have to look up the docs when writing or reading (or debugging) code. In the first version of my design, all methods will belong to a `Device` class, whose constructor accepts a single parameter that is an enum indicating the model of a device. For example:

```
  class Device
  {
  public:
       enum Model{ ABC , KLM , XYZ };
       Device( Model _model );        // ctor

       // Commands (encapsulate low-level instructions)
       inline void do_Foo();           // supported by all models
       inline void do_Bar();           // unsupported by 'KLM'
  };
```

However, in addition, I would like to prevent the command methods from being called if they are not supported by the model with which the `Device` was initialized. In fact, I would like to generate a compile time error if `do_Bar()` for example is called for the device model `KLM`. I've ruled out creating a class for each device model because this would involve creating scores of classes.

**Thoughts**

I've considered using the preprocessor directive `#error` in order to generate compile-time errors using the current device model as a predicate or precondition, although I'm not sure whether the preprocessor `#if..` macros support non-constants, such as my device models. In an ideal world a command method would be tagged with the methods that support and are therefore allowed to call it. Yet, and I hope I'm not asking for too much, I would like this to be done as easily as possible, so that adding support for newer devices is relatively simple and doesn't involve too many (error-prone) edits.

Afterthought: I realize by design may be flawed because all methods should be callable. I imagine that a subset of of valid commands can still be generated for each device using the STL, although I don't know which STL paradigm (e.g. traits) applies in this case.

Comment: You *can't*. Constructors are a run-time thing. Preprocessor directives are long gone by then.

Comment: Thanks guys. Grizzly, is there an STL paradigm that can be used to conveniently "declare" a subset of valid methods?

Comment: You **can**. Just throw away that enum and replace it with static polymorphism using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). See my answer for example code.

Comment: @ulidtko: Actually your statement says "you can't do it, however you can do something else instead", instead of saying that he can do that

Comment: @Grizzly that "something else" achieves exactly the goals he seeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do compile time decisions on something which is only known at runtime (like a parameter passed to a compiler).
Therefore you basically have two options:

1) throw an exception at runtime, when an unsupported method is called

```
inline void do_Bar(){
  if(model == KLM) throw runtime_exception("do_bar unsupported by device");
  ...
}
```

2) Create many classes, possibly through templates which contain only the appropriate methods. One way of doing that is the following:

```
  enum Model{ ABC , KLM , XYZ };
  template<Model M>
  class Device {
  public:       
       Device();        // ctor
       // Commands (encapsulate low-level instructions)
       inline void do_Foo();           // supported by all models
       template<Bool Dummy = true>
       inline typename std::enable_if<Dummy && (M != KLM), void>::type do_Bar(); // unsupported by 'KLM'
  };
```

The template parameter `Dummy` is needed, since `enable_if` depends on SFINAE which will only work it if the method itself is a template method and `enable_if` depends on the template parameter. Since it is  defaulted template parameter it doesn't need to be explicitely mentioned when calling the method, so

```
Device<ABC> d;
d.do_bar();
```

will still work (so no change in the interface there).

I used `std::enable_if`, which is only availible on C++11, if you don't have that you need to either use `boost::enable_if`, or write it yourself (its not that [hard](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php)).

The second option has the disadvantage that it is not possible to write code, which doesn't know the underlying model. On the plus side it allows you to mask slight differences in the offered interfaces through partial specialization (or using `enable_if`) to get different implementations for different models.

`boost::enable_if` is different from `std::enable_if` in that it takes a type as first parameter instead of a boolean. So one could either use `boost::enable_if_c`, which works just like `std::enable_if` or use `boost::enable_if` in conjunction with `boost::integral_constant` (which is part of Boost Type Traits, so include `boost/type_traits.hpp`):

```
template<Bool B> typename boost::enable_if<boost::integral_constant<bool, B && (M != KLM)>, void>::type do_bar();
```

Comment: I'm leaning toward this approach as I don't have to inherit and specialize. However I'm getting the enable_if constructs produces the errors `‘enable_if’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type` and `expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token` in g++ 4.5.3 on Cygwin.
(Note, I'm an STL novice but I'm now more than determined to learn it.)

Comment: @Olumide: As I mentioned `std::enable_if` is part of the new C++11 standard, so you need to compile with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` for gcc (for now, from 4.7 on `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11` also work) to get `std::enable_if`, otherwise you can try one of the other alternatives I mentioned like `boost::enable_if`, or writing one yourself (as shown somewhere on the site I linked to).

Comment: Okay, I'll take a closer look at `boost::enable_if`. I've tried using it a few days ago but I keep getting errors. Perhaps I should post my attempt and the errors that I get.

Comment: Would you care to correct my attempt. I've tried `inline typename boost::enable_if<M != KLM, void>::type doBar()` but I'm getting the error message `type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Cond, class T> struct boost::enable_if’` and `expected a type, got ‘(M != KLM)’`

Comment: @Olumide: certainly. Looking at the documentation `boost` uses `integral_constant` types instead of bools like the `std` version does. simply use `boost::enable_if_c` instead, which behaves like the `std` version or use `boost::enable_if<boost::integral_constant<bool, M != KLM>, void>` (I think, haven't worked with the `boost` version so far).

Comment: Thanks. `boost::enable_if_c` works. However, no other device types (other than the KLM) can be instantiated. I was hoping for a solution that would effectively delete the method if it is unsupported. (BTW, the `boost::integral_constant` produced lots of errors).

Comment: @Olumide: I do not understand what you mean. `boost::enable_if_c<M != KLM, void>::type doBar()` should disable `doBar` for `KLM` only. How exactly can't they be instantiated. Regarding `boost::integral_constant`: What kind of errors? I was pretty sure boost had an `integral_constant` somewhere in its type traits library, which works like the one in `std`.

Comment: I do not want the KLM Device to have a `doBar` method, as this 'command' is unsupported by this device. PS: I'll get back to you about the `boost::integral_constant` errors.

Comment: @Olumide: So how is the proposed code not working? Btw: maybe it would make more sense to reolve this in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec, since this might be alonger conversation

Answer (score 3):

What you need is essentially **static polymorphism**: varying compile-time properties of a class depending on its type. To be able to do that you need to replace the run-time model checking via that enum by compile-time checking using types. Just create a bunch of classes, one for each your model, and employ inheritance to share common code. [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) comes handy.

```
template<class Model>
class Device {
protected:
    void do_foo();
    void do_bar();
};

class ModelABC : public Device<ModelABC> {

};

class ModelKLM : public Device<ModelKLM> {
private:
    void do_bar(); // not available for this model, private!
};

class ModelXYZ : public Device<ModelXYZ> {

};

//-------- common implementation for all models

template<class Model>
void Device<Model>::do_foo() {
    std::cout << "Device::do_foo()\n";
}

template<class Model>
void Device<Model>::do_bar() {
    std::cout << "Device::do_bar()\n";
}

//-------- special implementation of method do_foo() for model XYZ
template<>
void Device<ModelXYZ>::do_foo() {
    std::cout << "special implementation of do_foo() for model XYZ\n";
}

void test() {
    ModelABC abc;
    ModelKLM klm;
    ModelXYZ xyz;

    abc.do_foo();
    klm.do_foo();
    xyz.do_foo();

    abc.do_bar();
    //klm.do_bar(); // compile-time error!
    xyz.do_bar();
}
```

---

Note that you can implement any model-specific behavior by specializing templates of relevant methods. Also you can make certain methods of a model inaccessible in compile-time by the private modifier.

---

**EDIT**

In a bit more declarative manner, you can use private inheritance to express which methods are *available* in each model, rather then which are not. Consider the code:

```
template<class Model>
class Device {
protected:
    void do_foo();
    void do_bar();
};

class ModelABC : private Device<ModelABC> {
public:
    using Device<ModelABC>::do_foo;
    using Device<ModelABC>::do_bar;
};

class ModelKLM : private Device<ModelKLM> {
public:
    using Device<ModelKLM>::do_foo;
};

class ModelXYZ : private Device<ModelXYZ> {
public:
    using Device<ModelXYZ>::do_foo;
    using Device<ModelXYZ>::do_bar;
};
```

This snippet is equivalent to the previous one: model KLM don't have `do_bar()` method, and model XYZ has specialized `do_foo()` method.

Comment: @Olumide I'll try to clarify my answer further. You **can** provide special model-specific implementations of methods by template specializations, and you **can** hide certain methods by making them private.

Comment: I see what you mean. I should override (but not implement) the definition of the unsupported methods -- nice. Unfortunately its counter-intuitive. I would be best to declare those methods that are supported.

Comment: @Olumide you can go that way too with `private` inheritance. `class ModelABC : private Device<ModelABC>`. Then you open up access to available methods by declaring them in the `public` section.

Answer (score -2):

Consider your Device class above. When you compile the class, the compiler creates a data block with enough space to allocate for the data members, and for the functions, it creates functions whose names are [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and a new parameter added to them, which is the 'this' pointer.

Your constructor too is just another function for the compiler, although the semantic analyzer takes care to see that it has no return type, but its just another function, i.e. a list of instructions at some memory address ready to execute. When functions are generated into machine code, all the compiler does is spit out instructions to set up a stack to hold parameters, spit out the actual function code and clear the stack. It has no idea of the value that may be stored in the parameters and hence it cannot be made to throw an error!

That said, you might consider using static analyzers like [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), where you can add your rules to analyze your code, and throw error on violating the rule accordingly. Hope this helps!